# css: mobile style being overridden by nested css

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have an element with 2 selectors.  When I shrink the screen to mobile view, I still see the width adhering to `isActive`'s width instead of the `100%` width of the `@include tablet-down` class.  In Chrome, I see that it is recognizing the mobile width but the `isActive` class has higher specificity so it is overriding it.  What is the best way to handle this so that it respects mobile width?

```
<div class="main isActive>

</div>  




.main {
   position: relative;
   width: 360px;

  &.isActive {
    width: calc(100vw - 500px);
  }

  @include tablet-down {
     flex: 0;
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need to add responsive css in isactive class like this: `&.isActive {
    width: calc(100vw - 500px); 
  @include tablet-down {
     flex: 0;
     width: 100%;
  }
  }`

Comment: thanks..is there anyway to do that dryer without code repetition?  I have a lot of uses of the `isActive` class throughout my HTML and I'd have to have to copy/paste all the mobile styles into there

Comment: I don't know the mixin you're using, but you could probably have something like that: `&.isActive { @include tablet-up { width: calc(100vw - 500px) }}`